# Bounded does not imply strongly continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given an operator $\Phi:B(H)\to B(H)$, where $B(H)$ denotes the Banach space of operators on Hilbert space $H$,  using the closed graph theorem, we can show that $\Phi$ strongly continuous implies $\Phi$ bounded.

However, the converse is not supposed to hold in general but I am struggling to come up with an example. For example,

$$a_n:H \to H$$

, the $n$th power of the left shift operator $e_i\mapsto e_{i-1}$ in $B(H)$, converges strongly to $0$ but not in the norm. How can I construct a bounded $\Phi$ such that for example, $\Phi(a_n)$ doesn't converge to $0$ strongly?

Comment: Would you mind defining what a "strongly continuous" operator is? Strongly continuous is usually used for a semigroup of operators, not a single one. And what is $H$, a Hilbert space?

Comment: @BrunoB We endow $B(H)$ with the strong operator topology i.e topology of pointwise convergence. $\Phi$ a linear operator on $B(H)$ is strongly continuous if it is continuous with respect to this topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are kind of on the right track with the shifts. Note that the adjoint of the left shit map is the right shift, which does not converge to $0$ in SOT.

This shows that the map $*:B(H)\to B(H)$ is norm continuous but not SOT continuous. The problem is that map this is not $\Bbb C$ linear but $\Bbb R$ linear. We can fix this by considering the transpose instead:

Let $H_\Bbb R$ be some real hilbert space, and $H=H_\Bbb R\otimes \Bbb C$ its complexification. The transpose map $^T:B(H_\Bbb R)\to B(H_\Bbb R)$ is $\Bbb R$-linear and continuous so we can extend it to a $\Bbb C$-linear  map
$$^{T_\Bbb C}:B(H_\Bbb R)\otimes \Bbb C = B(H)\to B(H_\Bbb R)\otimes\Bbb C=B(H)$$
Then if $L$ is a left shift on $H_{\Bbb R}$ you still have $L^{T_\Bbb C}=R$ and $^{T_{\Bbb C}}$ is not SOT continuous.